# Apply slicer filter when drilling into Pivot table

Tags: excel-2010, pivot-table

I have a pivot table with a couple slicers applied to it. The issue I'm having is when I double click a value in the pivot table, the sheet that's created has the appropriate pivot table filters applied, but *not* the slicer filters. Is there a way to do this without a macro?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more googling and found a way to pose the question that got me an answer. Here's the relevant site http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/03/22/drill-to-detail-with-excel-slicer-filters/

In short, you have to use a macro to apply slicer filters to the drill down.